# How to do asynchronous initialization in a RequireJS module

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, requirejs

I'm trying to create a module which need needs to fetch data from a URL before initialization is complete. I suspect I am missing something obvious but how to a make RequireJS wait until my async call is complete before the `require` call is satisifed.

```
// data module
(function() {
  Papaparse("http://url.csv", {
    complete: function(results) {
      /* need to return these results from this module after the async call */
    }
  });

  /* what do I return here? */
})

// main
require(["data"], function(d) {
  /* displays "undefined"  becase the async call is not complete yet */
  console.log(d);
})
```

Comment: I ended up using https://github.com/jokeyrhyme/requirejs-promise which has a good example how to solve it.   Both answered below are also correct but in my particular case requirejs-promise seed to fit better.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is an official plugin dedicated to this task: [text](https://github.com/requirejs/text)

Instead of splitting the process into two steps you'd just define the extra CSV data needed as a dependency, in the spirit of AMD/RequireJS:

```js
require(["./csvProcessor", "text!./url.csv"], function(CsvProcessor, csvDataString) {
  var data = Processor.process(csvDataString);
})
```

Note that the module's URL is still affected by the XHR limitations, as per [the documentation](https://github.com/requirejs/text#xhr-restrictions), so the data file will need to be hosted on the same domain your app is running from (unless using CORS, etc.).

Comment: This also help me find the requirejs-promis plugin.  But this answer didn't quite do it for me as I needed to use the PapaParse library to parse my CSV properly.  I guess I could have read the whole thing into CsvString and then parsed the string with Papa but it is a huge file and I thought that might be less efficient.

Both answers are correct but I marked this one since it suggests looking at RequireJS plugins which is how I ultimately solved my problem.

Comment: This is an answer to the details but not the question. The question is not "how do I load a text file", the question is "how do I do async initialization in a RequiresJS module". That there is a specific solution to loading text files is great but it's not actually an answer to the question. Example: I have an audio module. Many of the audio related apis are async. I need the module to wait for results before returning. Nothing to do with loading a text file.

Comment: @gman fair enough, one may argue that OP is the one to blame as they asked a specific question with a general title (and accepted an answer even though they admitted the solution was not a good fit)

Answer (score 3):

> It's a 6 year old question, but I've needed it before, and may again. I'll answer the general question of asynchronous module initialization:

You need an async loader plugin, such as `requirejs-promise` found here: https://github.com/jokeyrhyme/requirejs-promise - reproduced here, briefly:

```
define('promise', function(){var g=function(b){return b&&"object"===typeof b?window.Promise&&b instanceof Promise?!0:"function"===typeof b.then:!1};return{load:function(b,h,c){h([b],function(a){var d=function(){c.error.apply(null,arguments)};var e=function(){c.apply(null,arguments)};if(g(a)){var f=a.done||a.then;"function"===typeof a.fail?(f.call(a,e),a.fail(d)):f.call(a,e,d)}else c(a)})}}});
```

Here's a quick example using it (though you might typically load the plug itself and the async module via require):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <body>
  </body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Load requirejs-promise.js inline
    define('promise', function(){var g=function(b){return b&&"object"===typeof b?window.Promise&&b instanceof Promise?!0:"function"===typeof b.then:!1};return{load:function(b,h,c){h([b],function(a){var d=function(){c.error.apply(null,arguments)};var e=function(){c.apply(null,arguments)};if(g(a)){var f=a.done||a.then;"function"===typeof a.fail?(f.call(a,e),a.fail(d)):f.call(a,e,d)}else c(a)})}}});

    // An example async-loading module returning a promise (not
    // supported by vanilla requirejs)
    define('some-async-module', [], function() {
      return new Promise(function(res,rej) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          var module = { data:[1, 2, 3] };
          res(module);
        }, 2000);
      })
    });

    // Loading that module with promise! prefix
    document.body.innerHTML += 'Loading... 2 sec...<br>';
    require(['promise!some-async-module'], function(m) {
      document.body.innerHTML += 'Loaded async module: '+JSON.stringify(m);
    })
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: If for some forsaken reason you can rely on modern JS but still have to use RequireJS (like I do ), the promise plugin can be simplified to this: `define('promise',()=>({load(n,r,l){r([n],(s)=>s.then((...a)=>l(...a),(...a)=>l.error(...a)))}}));`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add promise to your load modules and return the promise .

Then the main.js need the business logic to determine finish once all promises are done
https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: This definitely pointed me in the right direction.  I wound up using the requirejs-promise plugin.   Which is basically just using a jQuery deferred under the covered.

Comment: Glad to hear it, mark as the right question then ;)

Comment: This isn't really an answer. Jquery as zero to do with RequireJS